# Getting 'Error (1): fast_xml_parser_1.XMLParser is not a constructor' whenever I am building the job on Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, deployment, sfdx

I am using 'sfdx force:source:deploy -x manifest/package.xml -u xyz@mail.test'  command to deploy the components to the salesforce using Jenkins.
But i am getting 'Error (1): fast_xml_parser_1.XMLParser is not a constructor' whenever I am building the job on Jenkins  which is based on AWS server can anyone suggest me something why this is happening as few days before it was working fine where I was using the same Jenkins script to build the job.

I tried the same script on localhost, it it working fine there. But failing on the Jenkins server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still looking for an answer, can you follow the below steps and see if it works:

1. Uninstalled current SFDX from Jenkins server
2. Download latest SFDx and install.
3. Jenkins will start working as expected.